# Error in creating Deployment YAML on kubernetes spec.template.spec.containers[1].image: Required value

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I have created an EC2 and install EKS on it.Then i created cluster and install docker image on it.
Now i'm trying to deploy this image to the docker container using given yaml and getting error.

```
Error in creating Deployment YAML on kubernetes 
spec.template.spec.containers[1].image: Required value
spec.template.spec.containers[2].image: Required value
```

--i can see the image on ec2 docker.
my yaml is like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: premiumservice
  labels:
    app: premium-service
  namespace: 
  annotations:
    monitoring: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: premium-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: premium-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "mp3-image1:latest" 
        name: premiumservice
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
      - name: type1
        value: "xyz"
      - name: type2
        value: "abc"
```

Answer (score 5):

The deployment yaml have indentation problem near the env section and should look like below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: premiumservice
  labels:
    app: premium-service
  namespace:
  annotations:
    monitoring: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: premium-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: premium-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mp3-image1:latest
        name: premiumservice
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
          - name: type1
            value: "xyz"
          - name: type2
            value: "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be totally unrelated, but I had the same issue with a k8s deployment file that had variable substitution in the image but the env variable it was referencing wasn't defined.

```
   ...
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: indexing-queue
       image: ${K8S_IMAGE}    #<--- here
```

Basically this error means "can't find/understand" the image you've set

Comment: Sigh - totally just spend half hour on this, only to find this answer helpful.  Then to realize I wrote this answer 8 months ago...